# `iptables` rate limiting & blocking IP addresses based on total download size?

Tags: iptables, rate-limiting

I have a webserver which serves either tiny, or very large files. I want to rate limit IPs by bandwidth. i.e. you can download X GB per day, and then you get blocked for Y hours.

Is it possible in `iptables` to  do this?

Presume Ubuntu 20.04 or recent Debian.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only shape/ratelimit certain flows using `tc`, but not block the user/IP after the limit is reached.

What you are describing here is an [*web-*]application logic that you can only implement yourself, for instance using lua with nginx.